# How do i get a member's id from their tag discord?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

How do I search for **example#0000** in a guild's member list and get their ID using discord.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user is cached then you can simply do:

```js
bot.users.cache.find(v => v.tag == "example#0000")
```

However if it's not cached then you search the guild members:

```js
guild.members.cache.find(v => v.user.tag == "example#0000")
```